# Looking for name of a famous matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix whose $(i,j)$-element is $1/(i+j-1)$. This is a famous matrix in linear algebra and has some nice properties (like, its inverse is integral).

Does anybody remember the name of this matrix? I am sure it was named after somebody but I don't remember. And I need the name for some reason.

Comment: The Hilbert matrix has entries $1/(i+j-1)$.

Comment: You are right, I meant 1/(i+j-1).


Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_matrix ?

Comment: comment, years ago, using a very easy method, I found an explicit formula for the inverse of Cauchy matrices and today when I was talking with somebody I could not remember its name.